# How to send structure data in socket programming?

Tags: ios, sockets, char, structure

I'm studying c socket programming lately,so I write an example for practice of Client–server model. I use structure as message data to send to server, server processes the data. when i run in the IOS simulator, it's right, but in the device it's wrong, I find that the structure data which the server receives from the devices client is different from the client message data! I'm sorry my English is very bad.

my structure code is:

```
 typedef struct Message
    {
        char msg[4000];
        char name[256];
        bool isBroadcast;
        bool islogin;
        USER userInfo;
    }__attribute__((packed)) MessageType;
```

user code is :

```
typedef struct user
{
    int id_number;
    char name[256];
    char password[20];
    char *p_chatlog;
    struct sockaddr user_addr;
    int sock;
} __attribute__((packed)) USER;
```

send code is :

```
MessageType *loginMsg = (MessageType *)malloc(sizeof(MessageType));
bzero(loginMsg, sizeof(MessageType));
loginMsg->islogin = true;
const char *name_str = [userName.text UTF8String];
memcpy(&(loginMsg->userInfo.name), name_str, strlen(name_str));

const char *password_str = [password.text UTF8String];
memcpy(&(loginMsg->userInfo.password), password_str, strlen(password_str));
write(m_sock, loginMsg, sizeof(MessageType));
free(loginMsg);
```

server receive code use read() function, then make the receive chars transform structure type.

Comment: could you please add USER structure definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you make sure you send the data in [network byte order](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/network_byte_orders.htm); use the [htonl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/htonl.3.html), htons and ntohl, ntohs system functions. Different devices may well be a different endianness. Also, you probably shouldn't just send a struct over the network, even in network byte order, you would be better devising a simple protocol to send the data you require - it's more maintainable and flexible. You also can't guarantee your write has sent all of the data you requested, you should check the return results of both your read and write to ensure you have the amount you expect.

Incidentally, it is recommended to avoid the POSIX networking library for iOS and use the native implementation where possible.

Comment: I find that some people say the endianness in the mac os is different and the the endianness in the iphone os is different. I go to try it! Thanks for your answer!!

Comment: I find my error is that server can't receive the whole data from client once, but I try to parse the data. Of course your answer make me know that I should study more about the transmission of socket data.